# How does ArcMap calculate the rotation of polygon labels?

Tags: python, arcmap, labeling

I am trying to duplicate some functionality in ArcMap,

ArcMap will rotate a label to fit inside a polygon. If you convert the labels to annotation this rotation value is available in the annotation table. How can I calculate a rotation for a label just using the polygon geometry and Python?

[image: Here is the label behavior I am talking about]